# Why does the projection of an image over 3d points show this distortion?

Tags: graphics, 3d, computational-geometry, projection

I have a question regarding the projection of an image over a set of 3D points. The image is given to me as a JPG, together with position and attitude information of the camera relative to a cartesian coordinate system (Xc,Yc,Zc and yaw, pitch, roll), as well as the horizontal and vertical field of view (in degrees).

Points are given using solely their 3d position in the same coordinate system (Xp,Yp,Zp).

In my coordinate system, Z is up. To project the image onto the points, I

- compute the vector from camera to each point

  ```
  Vector3 c2p = (Xp,Yp,Zp)-(Xc,Yc,Zc);
  ```
- rotate c2p according to my camera's attitude (quaternion):

  ```
  Vector3 c2pCamFrame = getCamQuaternion().conjugate().rotate(c2p);
  ```
- compute azimuth and elevation from the camera's "center ray" to the point:

  ```
  float azimuth = atan2(c2pCamFrame.x(),c2pCamFrame.y()));
  float elevation = atan2(c2pCamFrame.z(),sqrt(pow(c2pCamFrame.x(),2)+pow(c2pCamFrame.y(),2)));
  ```
- if azimuth and elevation are within the field of view, I assign the color of the corresponding pixel to the point.

This works almost perfectly, and the "almost" motivates my question. Let me show you:
[image: Diagram]

I cannot figure out why the elevation of the projection is distorted. In the bottom right of the image, you can see that points outside the frustum (exceeding the elevation) actually become colored - and this distortion is null at an azimuth of 0 degrees and peaks at the left and right edges of the image, creating the pillow distortion.

Why does this distortion appear? I'd love to understand this problem both in geometrical as well as mathematical terms. Thank you!

Comment: looks like precision problem are you using floats? 32/64/80/128 bit? what are the values of coordinates of points and camera what is the FOV of your frustrum (angle,znear,zfar). you are stacking many goniometric functions together per point may be better would be construct single transform matrix (computed in high precision) and use that for all points, If you got high dynamic range of positions then it could lead to distortions. recommend to use at least 64bit floating point types and as precise goniometry functions as you can (especially for atan2)

Comment: @Spektre, I don't think this is a precision isue. Yes, I'm using 32bit floats everywhere, but for all of the shown points in the example, the length of c2p is less than 200. Fov in degrees is 45h and 30v. Where exactly would I lose so much precision that my elevation is off by that much?

Comment: `c2p` is relative value what are the absolute values in global world ? if you are substracting things like `1000000000200.0-1000000000000.0=200.0` then this is precision thing if not then the issue may be elsewhere. As you did not provide example case data we can only guess. Also nesting too many goniometric functions affects this negativelly too ... Another thing is how did you render those images (with another projection?)  the problem may be there too...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The field of view angles are only valid on the principal axes. But you can do it the other way around. I.e. calculate the x/y bounds from the angles:

```
maxX = tan(horizontal_fov / 2)
maxY = tan(vertical_fov / 2)
```

And check

```
if(abs(c2pCamFrame.x() / c2pCamFrame.z()) <= maxX
     && abs(c2pCamFrame.y() / c2pCamFrame.z()) <= maxY)
```

Additionally, you might want to check if the points are in front of the camera:

```
     ... && c2pCamFrame.z() > 0
```

This assumes a left-handed coordinate system.

Comment: I tried this approach, and it seems to work. However, I'm wondering if it is accurate. I now determine the maximum deviations from the principal axes (maxX/maxY), then compare with the actual deviation to compute the pixel coordinates of the image. Am I not effectively linearizing a non-linear problem by doing so? Rephrased: will this also work accurately for wide-angle FoVs (assuming there's no lens distortion)?

Comment: There is no approximation here except floating point imprecision. The above explanations are valid for all models that project onto a plane (which seems to be the case in your problem). Projection on a plane is perfectly linear. Your approach assumed a projection on a sphere, which is non-linear, indeed.

Comment: I do project the image onto points that do not lie perfectly planar in space. In fact, in the image above, you can see the points approximate a slightly wavy ground, and later, I'd also like to project images on cylinders and other geometry. What exactly limits this approach to projecting images only on planes? Or are you just saying that the image sensor that captured the image in the first place has to be planar?

Comment: For other primitives (other than a plane), you would of course need other formulas. But as long as you project a planar rectangular image, the above formulas are fine. It doesn't matter how the points are distributed (whether they form a wavy ground or a cylinder).